# firebase storage for GIFS flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

i'm using firebase storage for my flutter app and now i have about 600 gifs in my firebase storage which consumes around 160 mega (all 600 gifs = 160 mega) and i want to copy the link of every gif and paste it in my app so that all the 600 gifs will be displayed in the screen.

so my question is, when 10k persons or even 100k persons access the same gif. it will mark as 10k reads or 100k reads ? is it works that way ? and if it doesn't, should i take something into consideration that i don't know like pricing or billing due to the amount of people who access everyday the gifs ? i mean the free plan of the firebase is enough for my desire ?

and another question, does the firebase change the links of the gifs that are stored in firebase storage due to many people who access the links within the app ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each of your 10k/100k users calls the Firebase API to load from Cloud Storage or uses the download URL that Firebase created, then Cloud Storage for Firebase will need to read the GIF for each of those calls - and this your project will have 10k/100k charged reads and the related bandwidth charges.

On your last question: the download URLs that Firebase generates are not changed by Firebase once generated. The only way those change is if you revoke the token in them from the web console for that specific file.